# Running a periodical background code in Flutter

Tags: flutter, background, fetch

I'm trying to use plugin named "Background Fetch" on Flutter Android.

It's supposed to awake the app every 15 minutes and call a callback.

When the app is in the foreground, it indeed launches a callback every 15 minutes,

But when I close the app, it fails to launch the callback every 15 minutes, claiming that "cannot find callback".

Is anyone here familiar with this?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart